# logspline produces incosistent results

Tags: r

I need my R scripts to always produce the same results for the same input. However, I've noticed that the function `logspline` from the package `logspline` produces different output on windows OS and ubuntu OS. Both uses `logspline` package 2.1.16, though.

Here's the code:

```
x <- c(0.3453205379,0.3497529927,0.3460179029,0.3433414591,0.3565925053,0.3318019585,0.3322091870,0.3314076990,0.3413768315,0.3305650805,0.3342775671,0.3362692445,0.3321054345,0.5982416984,0.5509602046,0.6600000000,0.3339818725,0.3307459063,0.3314632807,0.3356930476,0.3300000000,0.3324504116,0.3470739551,0.3441385006,0.3316070520,0.3399635743,0.3316989471,0.3308044524,0.3536822479,0.3315414656)
fnc <- logspline(x)
plot.logspline(fnc)
```

and here's the result on windows - fitted with 7 knots:
[image]
and here the result on ubuntu - fitted with 5 knots:
[image]

Could someone explain me the reason of the difference, please? And is there a way to force the function to produce consistent results in any environment?

**Output** `logspline(x, error.action=0)` **on windows**:

```sh
 knots A(1)/D(2) loglik     AIC minimum penalty maximum penalty
     4         2  40.53  -70.85          113.83             Inf
     5         2  97.44 -181.28            5.48          113.83
     6         2  99.48 -181.96              NA              NA
     7         2 102.92 -185.44           -0.13            5.48
     8         1 102.86 -181.90              NA              NA
the present optimal number of knots is  7 
penalty(AIC) was the default: BIC=log(samplesize): log( 30 )= 3.4
```

**Output** `logspline(x, error.action=0)` **on linux**:

```sh
 knots A(1)/D(2) loglik     AIC minimum penalty maximum penalty
     4         2  87.33 -164.46            8.38             Inf
     5         2  91.52 -169.44            2.07            8.38
     6         1  91.95 -166.88              NA              NA
     7         1  93.60 -166.78            0.00            2.07
     8         1  93.60 -163.38              NA              NA
the present optimal number of knots is  5 
penalty(AIC) was the default: BIC=log(samplesize): log( 30 )= 3.4
```

**Output** `sessionInfo()` **on windows**:

```sh
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] logspline_2.1.16

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.0 tools_4.1.0
```

**Output** `sessionInfo()` **on linux**:

```sh
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C             
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C           LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] logspline_2.1.16

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.0 tools_4.1.0
```

Comment: Interesting. I've got x86_64-w64-mingw32 and x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, both 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)

Comment: Convergence problems? What happens if you run `logspline(x, error.action=0)`. From the doc: *Very-very rarely
in some extreme situations logspline has convergence problems. The only
two situations that I am aware of are when there is effectively a sharp bound, but
this bound was not specified, or when the data is severly rounded*

Comment: I obtained the exact same output in my dual boot machine (Windows/Ubuntu) using: i) R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22), Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit), logspline_2.1.16 and ii) R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock", Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit), logspline_2.1.16. Could you please provide the sessionInfo in both environments?

Comment: why are you changing the number of knots between the two different machines? statistically plotting something with 5 or 7 knots is very different for splines.

Comment: Can you maybe show the output of a [`reprex::reprex()`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) on both systems as well as the output of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: @Mike, why do you think that I'm changing the number of knots? As you can see in the code above, I don't specify the it. I let the function use the *default knot-placement rule*

Comment: @David, I've added the output of sessionInfo(). What would be the output of reprex::reprex() good for?

Comment: good point, is your goal to always allow the function to choose the number of knots and it be consistent or is it fine to set it like my answer below?

Comment: When I run this code on Windows 10 with 4.1.0 and Ubuntu 18.04 with 4.0.2 and both package versions at 2.1.16, I get identical results, ie I cannot reproduce the error. @dpelisek the output of the reprex are created in a new environment and have everything that is needed to recreate the issue. With `reprex::reprex(session_info=TRUE)` you can even attach the session_info

Comment: @David, reprex::reprex(<the code above>, session_info=TRUE) renders exactly the same results as stated in the questions - 5 knots on linux, 7 knots on windows. Also the session information is identical with the one above.

Answer (score 6):

Not a complete answer, but this was way too long for a comment.

I tried different systems and this is what I found:

- docker: `rocker/r-base:4.1.0` returns **5** knots (`gcc` and `gfortran` version 10.2.1 `LAPACK` openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.13)
- docker: `rocker/r-base:3.6.3` returns **5** knots (`gcc` and `gfortran` version 9.2.1-30 `LAPACK` lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0)
- Fresh docker install Ubuntu 21.04 (alt 20.04) with 4.1.0 returns **5** knots (`gcc` and `gfortran` version 10.3.0 (9.3.0 for ubuntu:20.04) `LAPACK` lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0)
- Windows 4.1.0 returns **7** knots (not sure which `gcc`, `gfortran`, `LAPACK` version was used)
- Ubuntu 18.04 (docker) `ubuntu:18.04` with R 4.1.0 returns **7** knots (`gcc` and `gfortran` version 7.5.0, `LAPACK` version liblapack.so.3.7.1, alternatively tested with /atlas/liblapack.so.3.10.3, same results)
- Ubuntu 18.04 with 4.0.2 returns **7** knots (`gcc` and `gfortran` version 7.5.0 `LAPACK` libopenblasp-r0.2.20)

The package logspline uses multiple fortran and C functions, one of them being `nlogcensor`. The code below calculates many things, among others the `nknots`.

MWE for the internal code in `logspline::logspline` ([line 483ff of `R/logspline.R`](https://github.com/cran/logspline/blob/master/R/logspline.R#L483) in version 0.2.8 (github), for the CRAN version (current 0.2.16) it is line 486ff).

`logspline()` calls in `nlogcensor()` a C function which is defined in [`src/nlsd.c` at line 166ff](https://github.com/cran/logspline/blob/master/src/nlsd.c#L166) (latest version line 167ff).

```
library(logspline)
intpars <- c(30L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, -1L)
data <- c(0.33, 0.3305650805, 0.3307459063, 0.3308044524, 0.331407699, 
          0.3314632807, 0.3315414656, 0.331607052, 0.3316989471, 0.3318019585, 
          0.3321054345, 0.332209187, 0.3324504116, 0.3339818725, 0.3342775671, 
          0.3356930476, 0.3362692445, 0.3399635743, 0.3413768315, 0.3433414591, 
          0.3441385006, 0.3453205379, 0.3460179029, 0.3470739551, 0.3497529927, 
          0.3536822479, 0.3565925053, 0.5509602046, 0.5982416984, 0.66, 
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
          0, 0)
dpars <- c(-1, 0, 0)
maxp <- 65
kts <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
         0, 0, 0)

# actual code
z <- .C("nlogcensor",
        ip = as.integer(intpars),
        coef = as.double(data),
        dp = as.double(dpars),
        logl = as.double(rep(0, maxp)),
        ad = as.integer(rep(0, maxp)),
        kts = as.double(kts),
        PACKAGE = "logspline")

z$ip[2]
#> 7 some older systems, 5 for newer systems
```

This narrows down the source of error. And this is where my current journey ends. Unfortunately, I don't have much C experience and no FORTRAN experience.

I tried to follow the C routines, but the code is little formatted and hard to read for me. In [line 328 of `nlsd.c`](https://github.com/cran/logspline/blob/master/src/nlsd.c#L328) (version 0.2.16 line 335), the final `nknots` is assigned as `intpars[1]=(*spc).nk;` (C is zero indexed, R is 1 indexed).

Maybe you can reprodue the error using the `nlogcensor` code call and confirm different different Fortran or LAPACK toolchains.

### Answer Attempt

As can be seen from the text above, there is no simple way to make the package fully reproducible. That is, `set.seed(123)` and controlling the version of R and the package itself does not help as I suspect the toolchain version is different and leads to the differences.

The results from the different tests above suggest, that if you have a `liblapack` version >= 3.9.0 (or `libopenblasp` >= r0.3.13), you get 5 knots. Older versions lead to 7 knots.

As you usually have little control over this, you might want to look into docker and use a specified version, e.g., `rocker/r-base:4.1.0`. This might be a bit of an overkill for this problem (not sure how or for what you use the code), but this is the only way I currently see you can achieve full reproducibility as you have control over the toolchain as well.

Hope that clears your problem a bit or points you to a potential solution.

### Docker Scripts

In case you want to replicate the results:

For the `rocker/r-base` images, just use `docker run --rm -it rocker/r-base:4.1.0` and then within R `install.packages("logspline")` and the MWE code from above.

The full install script for `ubuntu` is a bit more complicated, see below:

```sh
docker run --rm -it ubuntu:18.04

# within the container

# install dependencies
apt update && apt upgrade && \
  apt install --no-install-recommends -y software-properties-common dirmngr wget build-essential gfortran 

# install r-base
wget -qO- https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/marutter_pubkey.asc | \
  tee -a /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc && \
  add-apt-repository "deb https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/" && \
  apt install --no-install-recommends -y r-base

# install lapack and blas
apt install libblas-dev liblapack-dev
# alternatively use this: libatlas-base-dev 

# install logspline
R -e "install.packages('logspline', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com')"

# see versions
gcc --version
gfortran --version
R -e "sessionInfo()" | grep usr

# run R
R
```

and then use the code from the MWE above.

Comment: this is about where I ended up too and also could not got much further but suspect that this is the source of error

Comment: The code in github is outdated. It has version `2.1.8` but OP is using `2.1.16`.

Comment: Good catch. Ill leave the links for now, the current lines can be seen from the edits of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The number of knots should be the same across machines to test if there is a difference. You must keep the number of knots the same because this will also change the statistical inference as well.

```
x <- c(0.3453205379,0.3497529927,0.3460179029,0.3433414591,0.3565925053,0.3318019585,0.3322091870,0.3314076990,0.3413768315,0.3305650805,0.3342775671,0.3362692445,0.3321054345,0.5982416984,0.5509602046,0.6600000000,0.3339818725,0.3307459063,0.3314632807,0.3356930476,0.3300000000,0.3324504116,0.3470739551,0.3441385006,0.3316070520,0.3399635743,0.3316989471,0.3308044524,0.3536822479,0.3315414656)
fnc1 <- logspline(x, nknots = 5)
plot.logspline(fnc1)
```

[image: nknots 5]

```
fnc2 <- logspline(x, nknots = 7)
plot.logspline(fnc2)
```

[image: nknots 7]

See I am testing only on windows but when you change the number of knots the graphics change.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! The "nknots" argument that you use only affects with how many knots the method starts. It ends with 7 knots (5 on linux) anyway. I'm surprise that it worked differently for you.

Comment: To further explain the problem and answer your question in the comments above;
when I run logspline(x, nknots = 5) on windows, I end up with 7 nknots anyway.
when I run logspline(x, nknots = 7) on linux, I end up with an error "too much data close together). So neither works for me.
Anyway, I need to run the same code for various input and thus letting the algorithm to find the best nknots would be preferable.

Comment: got it I understand now. I believe David's answer is most certainly on the right track maybe contact the authors of the package?